# Possessive of plural nouns

Tags: plural-forms, nouns, possessives

Which of the following is the correct possessive of *plural*?

- Peoples' homes
- People's homes?
- Peoples homes?

Comment: We need more context for this particular example. The word **people** can be either the plural or *person* or a singular noun meaning "group", and the correct answer will depend on its meaning.

Comment: replace people with houses, so would it be houses' doors ? i mean the doors for all the houses

Comment: I could have sworn this was a dupe but I can't find the other question. Maybe we need an in-depth post that goes through all possession rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule is that the apostrophe for a possessive comes after the *s* of a plural, but if the plural does not end in an *s*, add *'s*. The number of the noun being possessed is irrelevant grammatically; although it's usually plural, it could be singular in the case of something shared.

**Examples**

- doors of houses (plural, ends in *s*) -> **houses' doors**
- drivers of cars (plural, ends in *s*) -> **cars' drivers**
- houses of Charles (singular) -> **Charles's houses**
- houses of women (plural but does not end in *s*) -> **women's houses**